# iterate over jsonarray firebase cloud functions

Tags: json, node.js, firebase

I am trying to to parse json data from request body. The body I get in request is like :

```
{ members: '[{"ContactName":"abc","ContactNumber":"+92------","Turn":"28/04/2017","mData":0}]',
  cid: '-Kl8Yhi-3qCQ4E-iDFj6',
  committeedetails: '{"admin":"+923064664223","description":"xyz\\nMembers 1\\nPKR 10"}' }
```

and I get members from it as:

```
var body = req.body;
var members = body.members;
```

and console log for members is:

```
[{"ContactName":"abc","ContactNumber":"+92--------","Turn":"28/04/2017","mData":0}]
```

I want to iterate over this I have tried:

```
members.forEach(function(obj) { console.log("members",obj.id); });
```

Now issue is that I cant iterate over this json array. It throughs typo error :

```
TypeError: members.forEach is not a function
    at exports.shareTurnWithMembers.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:110:13)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:47)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:638:7
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:622:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

from some other questions I have also tried:

```
for(var i= 0; i<members.length; i++){
        var obj = members[i];
        console.log("members"+i, obj);
    }
```

and :

```
for (var key in members){
            console.log("members",key);
        }
```

these always through members length about 100. and log each character in the array.

Can anybody here correct me to iterate over json array containing json objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your `members` property is a string, while `forEach` only exists on an array (and a Firebase Snapshot).

For the moment you can iterate over the data encoded in the string by calling `JSON.parse()` on it:

```
var val = { members: '[{"ContactName":"abc","ContactNumber":"+92------","Turn":"28/04/2017","mData":0}]',
  cid: '-Kl8Yhi-3qCQ4E-iDFj6',
  committeedetails: '{"admin":"+923064664223","description":"xyz\\nMembers 1\\nPKR 10"}' };

var members = JSON.parse(val.members);

members.forEach(function(member) {
  console.log(member);
});
```

Work jsbin: https://jsbin.com/quboza/edit?js,console

But you really should figure out why the data is stored as a string, instead of as JSON.